# Why we have to use index!= -1 for comparing indexOf alphabets in java

Tags: java, string, indexing

I am unable to get why we should use idx != -1 in a if statement

here is my friend's code

```
public static String encrypt(String input, int key)
        {
            String alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            String shifted =alphabet.substring(key)+alphabet.substring(0,key);
            StringBuilder encrypted=new StringBuilder(input);
            for(int i=0; i<encrypted.length();i++)
            {
                char current=encrypted.charAt(i);
                int idx=alphabet.indexOf(current);
                if(idx !=-1) {
                    char newchar = shifted.charAt(idx);
                    encrypted.setCharAt(i, newchar);

                }

            }
            return encrypted.toString();


        }
```

please help me 
Thanks.

Comment: The result of `indexOf` will be -1 if not found

Comment: because `indexOf` will return the position of the `char` you are looking for in the given string.  If it does not find it, it returns -1

Comment: Take a look at the JavaDoc for `String#indexOf(int ch)` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-).

Comment: Because the publicly available documentation for the method you are calling suggests to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The line `int idx=alphabet.indexOf(current);` will return valid index 0~25 if its alphabet, if its not alphabetic character then it will return -1 as not found.

Answer (score 1):

**public int indexOf(String str)**  is the function from String class.
str is the search string you are looking for and it returns the location(index) where it is found.
If not found it will return -1

As you done want to do anything if you didnt find the character you are looking for, you need to compare return value with -1.